# Fix Corrupted User Profile on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, user-profiles

I have a bunch of problems with my PC and thanks to some comments in another (now closed) [question](https://superuser.com/questions/1591707/windows-resets-rollbacks-applications-after-each-restart?noredirect=1#comment2425585_1591707) I found that it is actually my user profile which was corrupted and 2nd (newly created) user is free from problems. But now I have 2 new questions? 1.Can I fix my 1st user profile? 2.If no then there is too much data in first user %AppData% (many android SDK, Python libraries and other stuff) that will take quite a lot of time to re-download/reconfigure, Is there anyway to move this stuff to 2nd user profile?

Comment: tbh I'd just work with the new profile and set it up again - it's more hassle than it's worth to try and bring over your app data

Answer (score 0):

You cannot fix a damaged profile. There is not any way to do that.

You can make a new profile with a different user name.

If you wish to use the same user name, do the following:

1. Copy all the data and email from the corrupted profile to a new neutral location (I use c:\temp)
2. Make or have a different user name that is a member of Administrators.
3. Log into the new user name.
4. Delete the damaged profile (step 1 was important). You can use Advanced System Settings for this.
5. Make your original User Name, log into it and recover the data from c:\temp

[image]